# Set variable to method

Tags: javascript, function

I want to make a shorthand library for myself, ex: shortening `querySelector` to `get`.

would there be a way to return just the method without `document`?

EXAMPLE:

```
function get(selector) {
  return .querySelector(selector)
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `document`?

Comment: If you work in a team, probably no one wants to use a non-standard library. Use jQuery, and you can write `$(selector)`, which is is even shorter than `get`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `.querySelector` on either the document or an element. It can't be left off. While you could pass it into the function...

```
const get = (context, selector) => context.querySelector(selector);
get(document, '.foo');
```

Having to write `document` each time you call it would be pretty repetitive. Just put it inside the function, there's nothing wrong with that.

```
const get = (selector) => document.querySelector(selector);
```

Another option (that I wouldn't recommend, since it mutates a built-in object) would be to add your method to `document`.

```
document.get = function(selector){
  return this.querySelector(selector);
};
```

or

```
document.get = (selector) => document.querySelector(selector);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const get = document.querySelector.bind(document);
```

this will work as it will preserve the context of document to querySelector's this

```
get('*') // will work while defining it as const get = document.querySelector wouldnt
```